# How can I share my X server between different PCs?

Tags: remote, x-server

I have a PC running the Reflection X X server. The display number is `5.0` and
I can direct processes to my own PC, e.g. `xeyes -display :5.0`

I want other PCs to be able to send `xeyes` to my PC.
I thought I could do it with `xeyes -display xx.xx.xx.xx:5.0` where `xx.xx.xx.xx` is my IP, but this does not work.
How can I enable displaying on my X server from other PCs or Linux desktops?

Comment: What error do you get when you run `xeyes -display xx.xx.xx.xx:5.0` on another machine?  I would guess this is an access control issue.  Assuming Reflection X is compatible with X.org, see ["Granting Access" from Xserver(1)](https://www.x.org/releases/current/doc/man/man1/Xserver.1.xhtml#heading10)

Comment: Try using `xhost`, read `man xhost`.

Comment: I don't get any error. seems like the xeyes is directed to somewhere invisible

Comment: I used xhost + to disable the x security. also the display from the other pc does not shown on mine.

Answer (score 3):

You have an X server running on computer A. You want to run a program on computer B, displaying on the X server of computer A.

From computer A, run an SSH client with X forwarding to log into computer B. In this SSH session, run the program you want to see on A's display.

```
ssh -X B xeyes
```

Opening an X display with `xhost +` only works if the X server is listening to TCP connections and no firewall gets in the way. Since it's very insecure (if someone can get access to your X server, they can take over your account), you should not use `xhost +`, and any tutorial that mention it should be burnt and forgotten.

Comment: the two computers are running x-server on one Linux machine. so when I do ssh -X B xeyes it is not acceptable because pc B cant get ssh. its a PC